# Intended Audience for N Is a Number?

Tags: soft-question

Is the film *N is a Number* appropriate (mathematically) for a student entering high school?

Comment: Appropriate by what metric?

Comment: Able to understand the premise, and generally what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, yes. It is focused mostly around anecdotes and mathematicians talking about their personal experiences with mathematics (Erdős related, of course). The explanations of mathematical theorems are oriented towards the general public, so they remain quite elementary. I really enjoyed this film, so I would highly recommend it to anyone. (I only wish more films like this were made. =))